# List of Supported MIME Types for Clipboard "write"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

My application generates a video file using the MediaRecorder api, of type `video/webm`.

I'm trying to copy this file to the clipboard by:

```js
const item = new ClipboardItem({['video/webm']: blob});
await navigator.clipboard.write([item]);
```

However I get the following error:

> ERROR DOMException: Type video/webm not supported on write.

What MIME types are supported for `clipboard.write`? Is there any video MIME type supported?

On Safari (Webkit), there are four supported:
https://webkit.org/blog/10855/async-clipboard-api/

- "text/plain"
- "text/html"
- "text/uri-list"
- "image/png"

Comment: This kind of question is not very fit for StackOverflow... Per specs, any format should be supported, but implementers can't possibly write the sanitizers for all formats. An answer today could be deprecated in a few days... Well, in fact the Raw Clipboard API is being abandoned by implementers: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1217643 They're looking at new proposals like https://github.com/dway123/clipboard-pickling So we can probably say that we won't ever have more than "text/plain" and "image/png" in Chrome .

Comment: I can't even handle this error with a `try ... catch`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Chromium, the following MIME types are supported:

- `text/plain`
- `text/html`
- `image/png`

Source: [`ClipboardWriter::IsValidType`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/modules/clipboard/clipboard_writer.cc;drc=e882b8e4a8272f65cb14c608d3d2bc4f0512aa20;l=304)

[This tracking bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1029857) tracks support for more formats.

---

Currently, there is a proposal to allow custom MIME Types: [Pickling for Async Clipboard API](https://github.com/w3c/editing/blob/gh-pages/docs/clipboard-pickling/explainer.md)

Comment: [Chromium 104+ supports "web custom formats"](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/web-custom-formats-for-the-async-clipboard-api/), which appears to be an implementation of the "Pickling for Async Clipboard API" proposal.